# React Native Redux actions not working without dispatch

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am pretty new to Redux, and I am implementing it for the first time in a new app I am building.

I have set up my `store`, `reducers`, `actions` and `selectors`. All is working, but with a slight caveat.

From my understanding, I can use

```js
// Other imports
import { setUserData } from '../actions'


const EditProfileScreen = ({ navigation, userData }) => {
   // Rest of component
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userData: state.user.userData,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setUserData })(EditProfileScreen)
```

which then allows me to use `setUserData` as a prop directly, and should use `dispatch`. However, when I simply call `setUserData(someData)`, my action is never called. Only when I have `const dispatch = useDispatch()` and then wrap my action as follows `dispatch(setUserData(someData))` does it work.

Fine, but I thought the whole point of the `connect` was to inject `dispatch` into my action creators?

I have seen elsewhere, implementations as follows:

```js
// Other imports
import { setUserData } from '../actions'


const EditProfileScreen = ({ navigation, userData }) => {
   // Rest of component
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userData: state.user.userData,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setUserData: () => dispatch(setUserData()),
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(EditProfileScreen)
```

So just to clarify, all functions as I want, I am just not sure what the correct way or best practices are.

Thanks

**Edit**

I have just realised, that I don't need to wrap my action with `dispatch()` if I use the below.

```js
const EditProfileScreen = ({ navigation, userData, setUserData }) => {
```

However, because I have to import `setUserData`, my lint flags that `setUserData` is already declared.

I suppose I can just rename the action in the props

Comment: Could you show the implementation of `setUserData` and how you're calling it in the component? It's not clear why it wouldn't be working. And yes, connect() gives you a component with props that you can simply call.